# How to append a widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter.

I am creating a chat app with websocket. I want to add a widget and append to another widget. What I am looking for is something similiar to jQuery append. I try StreamBuilder, ListView and after 4 hours of trying, googling, I have no luck.

This is my code

```
class ChatsDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatsDetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const ChatDetailPageData();
  }
}

class ChatDetailPageData extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChatDetailPageData({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ChatDetailPageData();
}

class _ChatDetailPageData extends State<ChatDetailPageData> {
  TextEditingController msgInput = TextEditingController();

  final _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('wss://echo.websocket.events'),
  );


  var chatCount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Someone'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black12,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: chatCount,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return _buildRow(index);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: msgInput,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                    hintText: 'Enter text',
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black26),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.send,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                onPressed: sendChat,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void sendChat() {

    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(msgInput.text);

    _channel.sink.add(msgInput.text);

    chatCount = chatCount + 1;
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    _channel.sink.close();
    msgInput.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _buildRow(int index) {
    return Text("Item " + index.toString());
  }
}
```

Please help, how to solve this.

Comment: are you trying to get input list on UI?

Comment: Hm... the layout looks like normal chat. There is a input box at the bottom. And in the body is where the conversation widget. What I want to achieve is to append a new widget every time it receives data from websocket. The widget can be list, container, text or anyting.

Comment: your channel seems return single string